# Fitness / Bootcamp retreats in South East Asia

Tags: thailand, indonesia, malaysia, southeast-asia, sport

I'm currently in Malaysia and have a few weeks before I have to move on. In this time, I'd like to take care of my fitness and join some sort of fitness / bootcamp retreat. So far, I found some expensive luxury retreats with lots of massages and spa treatments, but nothing with a serious fitness commitment. I'm looking for a place where they kick one out of bed at 5am for sports and have everything else taken care of as well (healthy food and time during the day to get some work done).

How would one find such a place? Anyone with personal experience?

Comment: While a question if such things exist or how to find one would be on topic, asking for recommendations of a specific service is not.

Comment: I (kind of) own an hotel on a desert indonesian island  island with healthy food for 10€ per day. Some local fishermen have a body-builder past and could be you full-time coach for 20€ per day.  Actually, I have this fantasy of turning it into what you describe